# Setting start date and due date in Redmine from email submission

Tags: redmine, email

I'm using Redmine's incoming email feature to create new issues however I'm running into problems passing in the start date and due date of the issue from the email.

This is the rake script:

```
rake -f [redacted other options] allow_override=start_date,due_date
```

Here are the relevant parts of the email:

```
Start date: 11/12/2012 
Due date: 11/15/2012
```

For some reason, all the other fields are passed through properly (including custom fields) however these two fields refuse to go through.  Any ideas as to how to properly pass through start and end dates for Redmine issues?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing, it's apparent that the date format for email submissions MUST be yyyy-mm-dd (regardless of the user-specified date format in the global settings)